# R: Cleaning up a wide and untidy dataframe

Tags: r, tidyr, data-cleaning, summarize

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
d<-data.frame(id=(1:9), 
                  grp_id=(c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3))), 
                  a=rep(NA, 9), 
                  b=c("No", rep(NA, 3), "Yes", rep(NA, 4)), 
                  c=c(rep(NA,2), "No", rep(NA,6)), 
                  d=c(rep(NA,3), "Yes", rep(NA,2), "No", rep(NA,2)), 
                  e=c(rep(NA, 7), "No", NA), 
                  f=c(NA, "No", rep(NA,3), "No", rep(NA,2), "No"))
>d
  id grp_id  a    b    c    d    e    f
1  1      1 NA   No <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2  2      1 NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   No
3  3      1 NA <NA>   No <NA> <NA> <NA>
4  4      2 NA <NA> <NA>  Yes <NA> <NA>
5  5      2 NA  Yes <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
6  6      2 NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   No
7  7      3 NA <NA> <NA>   No <NA> <NA>
8  8      3 NA <NA> <NA> <NA>   No <NA>
9  9      3 NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   No
```

Within each group (grp_id) there is only 1 "Yes" or "No" value associated with each of the columns a:f.

I'd like to create a single row for each grp_id to get a data frame that looks like the following:

```
grp_id  a    b    c    d    e    f
     1 NA   No   No <NA> <NA>   No
     2 NA  Yes <NA>  Yes <NA>   No
     3 NA <NA> <NA>   No   No   No
```

I recognize that the tidyr package is probably the best tool and the 1st steps are likely to be

```
d %>% 
   group_by(grp_id) %>%
     summarise()
```

I would appreciate help with the commands within summarise, or any solution really.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `summarise_at` and subset the first non-NA element

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
   group_by(grp_id) %>%
   summarise_at(2:7, funs(.[!is.na(.)][1]))
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#   grp_id     a      b      c      d      e      f
#    <dbl> <lgl> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
#1      1    NA     No     No   <NA>   <NA>     No
#2      2    NA    Yes   <NA>    Yes   <NA>     No
#3      3    NA   <NA>   <NA>     No     No     No
```

In the example dataset, columns 'a' to 'f' are all `factors` with some having only 'No' levels.  If it needs to be standardized with all the columns having the same `levels`, then we may need to call the `factor` with `levels` specified as `c('Yes', 'No')` in the `summarise_at` i.e. `summarise_at(2:7, funs(factor(.[!is.na(.)][1], levels = c('Yes', 'No'))))`

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'NA' not found.

Comment: @user2230555  As I am using your example, could it be a version issue.  I use `dplyr_0.7.4`

Comment: Ah, that may be it.  I'm using 0.7.1.  I'll update and try again.   Thanks.

Comment: Hhmmm, even with dplyr_0.7.4 I'm still getting that error.

Comment: @user2230555  Are you using the same example or different one?  Can u try `d %>% group_by(grp_id) %>% summarise_at(2:7, funs(if(all(is.na(.))) NA else .[!is.na(.)][1]))`

Comment: It works nicely with the example dataset (d), but not with my actual dataset.  I'm trying to figure out what's different between them.

Comment: @user2230555  That was what I was trying to understand.  Can u try `summarise_at(2:7,  funs(.[order(is.na(.))][1]))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159345/discussion-between-user2230555-and-akrun).

Comment: @G.Grothendieck  It can be solved easily with `factor` call.  Also, in the OP' example starts with inconsistent factor levels.  So I don't know which one the OP prefers

Comment: would you have a similar data.table way of doing ? I was trying to figure out a similar and simple way as in your answer but I didn't find.

Comment: @denis `setDT(d)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1]), by = grp_id, .SDcols = letters[1:6])`

Comment: @akrun Thanks! I think I never used the lapply this way, I learned something.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `aggregate`.  No packages are used.

```
 YN <- function(x) c(na.omit(as.character(x)), NA)[1]
 aggregate(d[3:8], d["grp_id"], YN)
```

giving:

```
##   grp_id    a    b    c    d    e  f
## 1      1 <NA>   No   No <NA> <NA> No
## 2      2 <NA>  Yes <NA>  Yes <NA> No
## 3      3 <NA> <NA> <NA>   No   No No
```

The above gives character columns.  If you prefer factor columns then use this:

```
YNfac <- function(x) factor(YN(x), c("No", "Yes"))
aggregate(d[3:8], d["grp_id"], YNfac)
```

**Note:** Other alternate implementations of YN are:

```
YN <- function(x) sort(as.character(x), na.last = TRUE)[1]

YN <- function(x) if (all(is.na(x))) NA_character_ else na.omit(as.character(x))[1]

library(zoo)
YN <- function(x) na.locf0(as.character(x), fromLast = TRUE)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've received some good answers but neither of them actually uses the `tidyr` package.  (The `summarize()` and `summarize_at()` family of functions is from `dplyr`.)

In fact, a `tidyr`-only solution for your problem is very doable.

```
d %>%
    gather(col, value, -id, -grp_id, factor_key=TRUE) %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    select(-id) %>%
    spread(col, value, fill=NA, drop=FALSE)
```

The only hard part is ensuring that you get the `a` column in your output.  For your example data, it is entirely `NA`.  The trick is the `factor_key=TRUE` argument to `gather()` and the `drop=FALSE` argument to `spread()`.  Without those two arguments being set, the output would not have an `a` column, and would only have columns with at least one non-`NA` entry.

Here's a description of how it works:

```
gather(col, value, -id, -grp_id, factor_key=TRUE) %>%
```

This tidies your data -- it effectively replaces columns `a` - `f` with new columns `col` and `value`, forming a long-formated "tidy" data frame.  The entries in the `col` column are letters `a` - `f`.  And because we've used `factor_key=TRUE`, this column is a *factor* with levels, not just a character vector.

```
na.omit() %>%
```

This removes all the `NA` values from the long data.

```
select(-id) %>%
```

This eliminates the `id` column.

```
spread(col, value, fill=NA, drop=FALSE)
```

This re-widens the data, using the values in the `col` column to define new column names, and the values in the `value` column to fill in the entries of the new columns.  When data is missing, a value of `fill` (here `NA`) is used instead.  And the `drop=FALSE` means that when `col` is a factor, there will be one column per level of the factor, no matter whether that level appears in the data or not.  This, along with setting `col` to be a factor, is what gets `a` as an output column.

I personally find this approach more readable than the approaches requiring subsetting or `lapply` stuff.  Additionally, this approach will *fail* if your data is not actually one-hot, whereas other approaches may "work" and give you unexpected output.  The downside of this approach is that the output columns `a` - `f` are not factors, but character vectors.  If you need factor output you should be able to do (untested)

```
mutate(value = factor(value, levels=c('Yes', 'No', NA))) %>%
```

anywhere between the `gather()` and `spread()` functions to ensure factor output.

Comment: Actually, because I used `select` I guess this answer is not `tidyr`-only.  Apologies.  But I still think this approach is worth considering.  If your data is not truly one-hot, this approach will have different failure modes than the `summarize_at` approach.

Comment: Wow.  I don't have this dataset open at the moment but I really appreciate the didactic and verbose explanation of what each command is doing!

Comment: I'm not sure if you are sarcastic or not, but being verbose and didactic was not my intention.

Comment: I am not being sarcastic at all!  That was a compliment.  I'm trying to learn the tidyr commands and this was really helpful teaching.

Comment: Ok, I've had some time to work through this now.  I agree that this approach is the most readable solution.  Also, thanks for introducing me to the term one-hot.